# How to make dynamic select field in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Actually, I have this select field to select the option which initially contains data "1".But if click on Add button then "2" should be added to the select field dynamically. I have tried but at first stage,2 is added but later on, it doesn't increase to 3,4,5.I just get 2,2,2,2.

```
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <select id="mySelect" size="1">
    <option id="option1">1</option>


  </select>
</form>
<br>


<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>

<script>

function myFunction() {

     var y = document.getElementById("option1").value;

    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = ++y;
    x.add(option);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, you need to set the `value` attribute as well since you use it in your `y` variable declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, with `var y = document.getElementById("option1").value;` you reset `y` to `1` all the time, hence it always become `2`. If you declare/init the `var y` outside the function it will work as is.

A simpler solution could be to get the amount of `option` elements, using the `select`'s `length` property, and add `1` to it.

Stack snippet

```html
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <select id="mySelect" size="1">
    <option id="option1">1</option>


  </select>
</form>
<br>


<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>

<script>

function myFunction() {

    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = x.length + 1;
    x.add(option);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Here is an updated version of the existing solution, e.g. declaring the `var y` outside the function.

```html
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <select id="mySelect" size="1">
    <option id="option1">1</option>


  </select>
</form>
<br>


<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>

<script>

var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("option1").value);

function myFunction() {

    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = ++y;
    x.add(option);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @KarkiAshwin That's fine, just wanted to make sure it helped :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```html
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <select id="mySelect" size="1">
    <option id="option1">1</option>


  </select>
</form>
<br>


<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>

<script>
var count = document.getElementById("mySelect").options[0].value;
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = ++count ;
    x.appendChild(option);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/au0qdtj1/22/

Comment: Furthermore, answers saying "Try this" and with no explanation what so ever is pretty useless and considered a bad answer.